# Windows 10 IoT 15063 Device Portal Apps page shows no "Add" option

Tags: windows-iot

Raspberry Pi 3 with a 16GB Class 10 card.

I am attempting to install some AppX packages to my RPi running W10 IoT Core. I downloaded the packages from Windows Store on ky computer and opened the Windows Device Portal in MS Edge. I uploaded the packages and pressed "Go" under "Deploy" tab, but nothing seems to had changed. I noticed that all screenshots found online had a blue "Add" button adjacent to the "Check for updates" button, but mine did not. So what's wrong with this?

Comment: Maybe you have an old Version of Windows IoT Core. The really old ones did not have an automatic upgrade feature, only the newer version. Try and flash to the latest version

Comment: @ppumkin It's already the newest from MSDN.